# (android) Am I set the category communication in admob and I set the category education in android market?

Tags: android, admob

Am I set the category communication  in admob and I set the category education in android market?

I mean if I do that ,there is any problem? Because there is not education category in admob but my app is education app. 
I set the communication category in admob but in android market I set it to education is it problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admobs settings for category and such is only so it can show more relevant ads. It should still work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Admobs settings are for category of ads you want to show in your app, it doesn't effect which category your app is uploaded to market. It should be fine.